# CSS secting div under div-group

Tags: css, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<div class=1><div class=active></div></div>
<div class=2></div>
```

CSS:

```
.1 {}
.2 {display:none;}
```

How can I select the second div when inside div is active?
Actually, change to **display:block**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** It appears you don't want the parent element's style to change. Instead, you want the second `<div>`s class to change if the first `<div>` contains a child-element with the class: active.

```
if ($(".one > div.active").length > 0) {
    $('.two').css("display", "block");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5rphc/2/

Comment: Correct! How can i do that?

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Do i have to insert classes in this code?

Comment: No, this is what you need to do. Check the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rphc/

Comment: **Also:** Don't start CSS classnames with digits.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work again. What can i do with this - http://jsfiddle.net/KegP/5rphc/1/

Comment: Well, once you INSERT a `<div class="active">` INSIDE the parent `<div>` it will become visible. If that is now what you try to do please explain yourself better and/or provide more code.

Comment: I like to believe I now understood what your question was. I updated my original answer. Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.1:active > .2 
      { 
         display: block; 
      }
```

the ">" means a "sibling" operator in CSS

Comment: I need to select through both div.
Because active class appears during selecting category шт menu.
Like div.1 div.active + div.2 {display:block;}

Comment: No, `>` means child, not sibling.

Comment: oh sorry. Yeah, "+" operator was actually the one for sibling